# Criteria to get all domains with collection less than property

Tags: grails, criteria-api

Given the following domain class:

```
class Game {
    Integer maxUsers
    static hasMany = [users: User]
}
```

Using the Criteria API, what should I do to get all domains with the number of users less than `maxUsers` property?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not just using a `size` constraint on `users`? It would seem to me that if you have a maximum number of users, then you'd be enforcing that somehow, and therefore the `users` list would *never* exceed `maxUsers`.

Comment: maxUsers property may be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do with Criteria api, as Hibernate Criteria don't support HAVING clause. There is an open [JIRA issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1043) for that, you can try patches submitted there.

An alternative would be to use HQL:

```
def results = Game.findAll("from Game where id in (select g.id from Game g join g.users u group by g.id, g.maxUsers having count(u) < g.maxUsers)")
```